# How can I add a column to the line items table in /admin/commerce/orders/[order-number]/edit

Tags: hook, drupal-commerce, orders

I can't seem to find how Drupal is building the line items table? It's not a view (that I can find, at least) and I'm not sure how to override it? I'd like to add a column that displays a custom order field I've added to the Order type.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you using the Inline Entity Form module.

The simplest way to override it's output is to replace it with views. In order to do this:

1. Create new View that displaying line item entities
2. Switch output to this view here: admin/commerce/config/order/fields/commerce_line_items/widget-type

However, if you want to play with IEF API you can look for hooks [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/108059/34109).